# Drive the value of a Follow Path constraint

Tags: drivers

I have a project where I would like to use a bones rotation value to move another bone along a brzier curve.

I have a bezier curve with the bone that is constrained to the curve with a "follow path " constraint.

I have the bone i want to use to drive the "offset" value of the follow path constraint.

I run into a problem where the driver is affecting the bone to fast. It seems the conversion the driver is doing is muddled.

I have a link to my file.

Please help if possible!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGM6t1OQX3MvETzCNrDbSz-EiSbqyI_W/view?usp=sharing

my objective is to rotate a bone  and have it drive another bone along the bezier curve. I wish for the main bone that is driving the bone on the path to complete a full 360 degress before the bone on the path finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click on the Offset value of your constraint.  Add driver ->
   Scripted Expression (don't worry, no script needed)
2. Open a Driver Window (Shift F6)
   [image]
3. In the driver select the armature as the object, and the control
   bone as the bone.
4. Choose Y location and local space.
5. The expression should just be var, nothing behind it.
6. Move the controller in local y direction (in your scene global z)

Comment: Hi Frederik!  Thanks for helping! I have tried your setup but I cannot get it to work in Local space. Also I need the x rotation to drive the value. here is an updated file where i have tried what you have shown me.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1miPPLz-mB4seQJUuzO6Crc08e9CbQNU2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks again for your help

Comment: That setup works... You should join the armatures though, In object mode, select the big bone, shift-click on the smaller one, press CTRL J, go into pose mode and select bigger bone, press R -> X and move your mouse.

Comment: ah cool this is getting good! Just one more thing if you are up for it.  In this next updated file everything is looking great thanks to your help! I need the animation to complete in one revolution of the main bone. so far I get to around 60 degrees and then the animation reaches the end. Do you know how to fix that to one full rotation? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iFSHUTIPvYBCc4UORXw9KrjIEWQ54bTX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Easiest way to do that is: Select the bone, press n, goto your start frame, hover your mouse over the rotation, press I, go to the end frame, in the x rotation type 360, with your mouse still over the rotation, press I again.

Comment: you can easily do that as well. var / 10 will make it 10 times less sensitive. If my answer solved the problem, could you mark it as accepted, so others don't have to click on the answer to find out if it's solved?

Comment: sorry I was not specific with my question. I know how to aimate keyframes. I am wondering how to match a full rotation of the driving bone with the full length of the follow offset .

Comment: Here is a file. I applied var /10 . The animation is now slower but the bone that is being driven does not complete the full path of the curve. instead it reset when the driver bone rreaches 90 degrees  https://drive.google.com/file/d/19fpVGf64twpGOEqf8B1xrPVjeSqwC3Z7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you are very helpful and I thankyou for your time.

Comment: Internally, rotations are stored in radians, not degrees, so rotating about 6° would be completing the full path. All you need to do treat it like radians, so divide the value by 2 * pi -> var / 2 / pi

Comment: I tried the math. It accepted the algorithm but it did not change the outcome. It remained the same. If you would like to look at the file i have included it with the math you recommended.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ygDMsHmGyffcPg3qovZ790YlmPKjlWww/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Switching to Euler was the right step., but now your bone has a y rotation > 0. In cases like this, you should only rotate the axis you're interested in. Clear its rotation and it works.

Comment: how about that... it works! Thanks so much for your time and effort